# Using AWK for multiple searches

Tags: bash, logging, awk, sed

Trying to learn how to use awk, grep, cut etc. to search logs.

```
tail -n +1 logfile.log | grep 'path=/select' | awk '{print $7"\t"$4}' | sed 's/QTime=//g' | sort -rn | less
```

Currently this brings the Qtime to the beginning of the line in a new column so I can sort by the highest time. What I am now trying to figure out now is how to pull another value,  watchlist_8:*) from the same line to do a similar new column. The delimiter : after watchlist is the 11th.

Output expected:

> Qtime  Watchlist
>
> 12899  watchlist_8

I would also be happy if "watchlist" was set to color if all else fails.

Comment: When you're using awk you never need to additionally use grep, cut, and sed. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. Use the editor's `{}` button to format it properly.

Comment: You can use the `split()` command in `awk` to split on `:`.  Without knowing the layout of `logfile.log` it is difficult to be precise, but you should be able to do it all in `awk`.